# Not able to achieve synchronization with the help of Synchronizing timer in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, synchronization

Building a test plan in JMeter. I have different Transactions and each of them has number of HTTP samplers and **"if conditions"**.

So basically each user might not perform the same action based on the **"if condition"**. I want all the users to start performing the same transaction at the same time and also wait for the other users(Threads) if they have not reached to the current transaction.

I know that I can achieve this with the help of Synchronizing timer but somehow I am not able to achieve this with it.

How to achieve it with any possible method ?

PS - I just want the threads to start transaction at the same time. it does not matter if they performing same sampler or not.

Comment: I was thinking can I use BeanShell preprocessor for it? How can I simulate synchronization with the help of BeanShell preprocessor? I just want all threads to start a transaction at the same time. I dont want all the samplers inside the transaction to be synced. I just want them to start the transaction together.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest another approach,

You can use [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group),

> execute after the test has finished executing its regular Thread Groups.

After **all threads are done** you execute tearDown and can execute anything you want, including [Module Control](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) which can reuse transaction from your main thread group

Comment: I was thinking can I use BeanShell preprocessor for it? How can I simulate synchronization with the help of BeanShell preprocessor? I just want all threads to start a transaction at the same time. I dont want all the samplers inside the transaction to be synced. I just want them to start the transaction together.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to guess what's going wrong without seeing your Test Plan structure. Just in case be aware that Timers obey [Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) so if you want a request to be executed by N threads in parallel - you need to put the Synchronizing Timer **as a child** of this request.

See [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) article for comprehensive information and example test plan.

Comment: I was thinking can I use BeanShell preprocessor for it? How can I simulate synchronization with the help of BeanShell preprocessor? I just want all threads to start a transaction at the same time. I dont want all the samplers inside the transaction to be synced. I just want them to start the transaction together.